# Unable to install Bookdown via devtools on Big Sur

Tags: r, bookdown

As the title says, I am unable to install Bookdown via devtools on macOS Big Sur:

```
Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/bookdown@HEAD
Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/rmarkdown@HEAD
Installing 1 packages: tinytex
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.0/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://lib.ugent.be/CRAN/src/contrib/tinytex_0.27.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 27492 bytes (26 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 26 KB

Error: (converted from warning) Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C"
Execution halted
Error: Failed to install 'bookdown' from GitHub:
  Failed to install 'rmarkdown' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘tinytex’ had non-zero exit status
```

I get similar warnings when starting R:

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C"
```

My system is set to US English. The output of `locale` is:

```
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

The suggestion I found online is to run `defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8` first, but that didn't change anything for me.

Comment: You might need to install tinytex manually — check https://yihui.org/tinytex/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround that does seem to work is to explicitly set LC_ALL when launching R (or Rscript):

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" R
```

Setting this in R itself didn't work.